# Android - Calling getJSONArray throwing JSONException without stacktrace

Tags: android, json, getjson

I'm currently working on an android app that pulls a list of forums from a JSON feed.  I'm trying to parse the feed and immediately upon calling getJSONArray a JSON exception is being thrown with no stack trace.  The JSON being returned is stored in an JSONObject jobj with the format as follows:

```
{
    "Forum":
        [
         {"ForumName":"CEC Employee Communications Forum","ForumId":"105"},
         {"ForumName":"CEC External Stakeholder Relations Forum","ForumId":"109"},
         {"ForumName":"See All...","ForumId":"0"}
        ]
}
```

However when running the following code, I get an immediate exception without a stack trace:

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("Forum");
```

Running

```
jobj.GetJSONArray("Forum").toString();
```

returns what looks to be a correct array of the format:

```
[
 {"ForumName":"CEC Employee Communications Forum","ForumId":"105"},
 {"ForumName":"CEC External Stakeholder Relations Forum","ForumId":"109"},
 {"ForumName":"See All...","ForumId":"0"}
]
```

I also tried

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jobj.GetJSONArray("Forum").toString());
```

and had the exception thrown immediately.

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this doesn't help?  I doubt you can get an Exception without a stacktrace:

```
JSONarray jarray = null;
try {
   jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("Forum");
}
catch(JSONException je) { je.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: I tried that and put a break point on the line but it skipped right over it and printed nothing in the log.